# How to avoid FPS drop on games after the laptop battery dies?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, cpu-speed, fps

I am having an FPS drop when I play games (e.g., League of Legends).
When I bought my Laptop PC (DELL INSPIRON N5110) I didn't experience the FPS Drop, it was around 60 FPS and stable. It started when my battery died and doesn't charge anymore.

I have been looking on Internet for a solution for months, I found out that I have to trick my windows and disable CPU Throttling. I tried it but I can't manage to do it on my windows 7.
I hope someone will able to give me a solution for my lifetime problem and Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound like a problem caused by battery, and if it is, disabling CPU throtting wouldn't help.

Throttling happens when CPU is too hot. Clean the dust inside, maybe replace the thermal compound on CPU and GPU. Make sure the cooler is working.

Disabling throttling is dangerous. Thermal throttling prevents your CPU from damaging itself by overheating. Disabling it is not a good idea.

Comment: Ok I would not want to disable CPU throtting aswell, but I am sure this problem started when my battery died, and to be sure it is, when I bought a new battery the fps came back to 60 and stable. I dont understand

Comment: That's interesting. Anyway, sounds like you have a new battery and everything is back to normal, what's the problem?

Comment: It died too, so I returned to the initial problem, I need a solution because buying a new battery every 6 months is not the thing that I intented to do when I bought my laptop pc.

Comment: It sounds like there's some funky power management throttling going on. It's pretty common for systems to work at full speed while on AC and then throttle down for battery life, but I've never heard of the reverse. @Fnayou, how does the system behave when there is no battery whatsoever attached when plugged into the wall?